Camera view not adjusting as camera moves along its Local Axis
In the images below, we can see a vertical split of the screen. On the left is the camera view, on the right is the viewport view.
While moving the camera along its Local Axis, I expect the camera view on the left to expand, covering a wider space, but it just gets stuck on that particular view regardless of how close or how far the camera is.
In simpler terms, the farther you get from an object, the smaller it becomes(and vice versa), but here its just stuck on the same view.
Is there a way to get this back to what it should be?


Camera Type is orthographic. Viewport projection is Orthographic, and Orbit and Pan Auto perspective is toggled off.

If the camera is in Orthographic mode, its distance to the object doesn't matter, if you want to have a larger view you need to change the Orthographic Scale:


This is MIND blowing. I'm just learning about this. Thank you.

@OgunlesiTaiwo What is more mind-blowing: Consider that you can't build an orthographic camera in real life - unless maybe if you design a sensor so large that its area is equal to that of the subject to be captured (meaning no lens perspective). Expect it to be astronomically expensive and impractical. But you can get a good enough approximation to a flat field of focus with a macro lens, which is what photographers use to capture large art prints, murals, etc. So you can think of it like the ortho setting allows you to cheat and do something practically impossible with a physical camera. :-)
